# R: Generate unique, non-overlapping intervals

Tags: r, intervals

Suppose I have a set of start and end points e.g.

```
0  10
8  10
10 20
10 20
25 30
40 50
45 55
```

and I would like to get all unique, non-overlapping intervals

```
0   8
8  10
10 20
25 30
40 45
45 50
50 55
```

How can I do this in R? Using base R, or any package should be fine.

MWE

```
matrix( c(0,10,8,10,10,20,10,20,25,30,40,50,45,55),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Why do you choose `0 8` and `8 10` as opposed to `0 10` ? Can you be a bit clearer about how you select an interval?

Comment: Maybe see packages `intervals` or `set`, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381212/interval-sets-algebra-in-r-union-intersection-differences-inclusion).

Comment: I'm aware of the `intervals` package, but I wasn't able to find a function that did exactly what I wanted. I will probably have to write up something custom

Comment: What if the input was (0,20) and (5,10). What would the expected output be?

Comment: (0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an awkward solution using the `intervals` package

```
x <- unique(Intervals_full(matrix( c(0,10,8,10,10,20,10,20,25,30, 40,50,45,55),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)))
closed(x)[1:length(x)]<-FALSE

z <- interval_overlap(x,x)
y <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(z)){
  if( length( z[[i]])==1){
    y <- rbind(y,x[i])
  }
  for(j in z[[i]]){
    if(i != j){
      y <- rbind(y,interval_difference(x[i],x[j]),interval_intersection(x[i],x[j]))
      y <- rbind(y,interval_difference(x[j],x[i]),interval_intersection(x[j],x[i]))
    }

  }
}
y <- unique(Intervals(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Going in a bit naively, this seems to work for your specific example:

```
matrix( c(0,10,8,10,10,20,10,20,25,30),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)->mfoo

sort(unique(as.vector(mfoo)))

[1]  0  8 10 20 25 30
```

Comment: This is almost what I want, but it doesn't handle the case when there is not complete overlap. I added another example interval. I will probably just have to code something up.

Comment: I get your desired result with your new example, with the possible difficulty that you need a way to reject `30 40` .  I don't think that will be hard to do: try comparing my output with the first column of your input, possibly.

Comment: I see, every pair of your output produces all of the desired outputs, but also more (as you stated. notice also with my new example it also produces (20,25) ).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using `disjoin` function from the bioconductor package `IRanges`:

```
require(IRanges)
ans = disjoin(IRanges(x[,1]+1L, x[,2])
# IRanges of length 7
#     start end width
# [1]     1   8     8
# [2]     9  10     2
# [3]    11  20    10
# [4]    26  30     5
# [5]    41  45     5
# [6]    46  50     5
# [7]    51  55     5

start(ans) = start(ans)-1L
# IRanges of length 7
#     start end width
# [1]     0   8     9
# [2]     8  10     3
# [3]    10  20    11
# [4]    25  30     6
# [5]    40  45     6
# [6]    45  50     6
# [7]    50  55     6
```